# Show animation while waiting for external ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A JavaScript for GUI manipulation calls JavaScript for data handling. I want to show an animation while waiting for the external ajax-request.
For example: `gui.js` has the method `showData(id)` and `data.js` has a function `getData(id)`. Inside `showData(id)` I call `getData(id)`. Inside `getData` is an `$ajax` for getting data from the database. I want to show an animation while `showData(i)` waits for `getData()`.

I have found a lot for making an ajax-request after another ajax-request was successful, but no solution for my problem.

UPDATE:
Get Details at the moment. Maybe i could return the $.ajax and make it asynchron.

```
function getData(id) {
var ajaxResult = $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/ajax/getData.php',
    data : {'id' : id},
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    error : function() {
        console.log("FAILURE on getting" + id);
    }
});
return ajaxResult.responseText;}
```

The showData should call getData().

```
function showDetails(id) {
$('#ElementInfo').html("");
var jsonData = getData(); //while that show load
//hide load animation
$('#ElementInfo').html(makeHtml(data));}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't find anything related to your question on internet?

Comment: lets say there is an element with ID `someId`, where you want to display the content that is returned from the ajax response. Add you animation to the that element with id `someId` and make `someId`'s length zero (the animation will be hidden) when the data is returned, and append the response to that element with id `someId`. It should work

Answer (score 2):

Add your animation in an html element.

Immediately before the ajax request "show" the element.  On "success" from the ajax request, "hide" it again.

ie.

html

```
<div class="animation">animation here</div>
```

js

```
$("#animation").show()
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/whatever/url"
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response){
        $("#animation").hide();
        //then do what you need to do with your response
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Why `visibility:hidden`? Why not `display:none`

Comment: Sry my Problem is, I am not allowed to change GUI from the ajax-Request inside getDetails. To explain it better: I want to make an AjaxReqest inside showData(id) waiting for complete the ajax-Request from getData(id).

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Classes one is to make div hidden.

```
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

Second one to show image.

```
.show_image{
position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) url(/img/spinner.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
z-index:100;
background-size: 5ex;
}
```

And your HTML code would be

```
<div class="show_image hidden"></div>
<div class="box"> Your  content </div>
```

Initially loading image is in hidden mode. Now before sending your Ajax request just unhide the loading image and after getting the server response make it hidden.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://wwww.example.com",
            type: 'POST',
            data: yout_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            //async: true,
            //cache:true,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            $('.show_image').addClass("hidden");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("error: load handler failed: " + url);
                result = "null";
            }
        });
```

Loading image will be appear at the middle of the page and background will become transparent. Please let me know if you found any difficulties.

As per your code:

```
function showDetails(id) {
$('#ElementInfo').html("");
 $('.show_image').removeClass("hidden"); // Now the image will be displayed 
var jsonData = getData(); // it will request the data to be return
// in the ajax request i have stopped animation "in success" 
$('#ElementInfo').html(makeHtml(data));}
```

Comment: I know the normal way to do this, but i want to wait for another ajax Request. Maybe i should use when(). Before when() i show the wait and after when i hide it. but i need the data from the getData()-Request to show it in showData().

Comment: When you call Ajax POST/GET request , first we will show the image (using beforeSend), then after getting the response from the server we will be hiding that image(Using success). This what we call waiting time. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes thats right. But inside the $ajax from getData() i want not to manipulate the Webpage. Inside showData i want to get the data from getData show it and after that hide the animation.

Comment: Can you please post your code $ajax,getData etc functions that you have written, So that i can visualize your problem

Comment: Thanks for your code. There is no much difference, you are asking me to start animation before you call "getData()" after getting the data animation should be stopped. Ajax itself will do all these things. But anyways i have edited the above answer have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in your shown ajax request you change the class inside getData(). But in my given architecture I am only alowed to change the class inside showData(). In showData(id) i want use getData(id) to get the informations from 'id', only. My question is: Is there a way to wait for getData(id) and during waiting add a class and after response get the information and remove the class.